# Redirect to homepage from splash page magento

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I am trying to redirect to my homepage from a splash (age verification) page, and it just keeps popping up the same age verification page.

I have the ageVerify.php script in the root folder and I have the other script at the top of my template file page. I just need to find the correct file structure format to redirect too after someone hits "yes i'm 18"

The code below doesn't work when added to the top of my column1.phtml file - it just keeps going back and recalling the verify.php script. Any ideas would be very helpful!

```
<?php

function verified()
{
    $redirect_url='http://www.johnsoncreeksmokejuice.com.vhost.zerolag.com/verify.php';
    $expires=-1;
    session_start();

    $validated=false; 

    if (!empty($_COOKIE["verified"])) {
        $validated=true;
    }
    if (!$validated && isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated=true;
    }
    if (is_numeric($expires) && $expires==-1 && !isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated=false;
    }
    if ($validated) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $redirect_url=$redirect_url."?return=index.php&x=".$expires;
        Header('Location: '.$redirect_url);
        exit(0);
    }
}

verified();
?>
```

Comment: So I add this where it says cookie above??? I'm confused where am i adding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chose to use a javascript alternative. Worked out much easier for me:

```
function writeCookie(key,value,days) {
    if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = key+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(key) {
    var nameEQ = key + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


function ageGate() {
    var monthDays = {
        1: 31,
        2: 29,
        3: 31,
        4: 30,
        5: 31,
        6: 30,
        7: 31,
        8: 31,
        9: 30,
        10: 31,
        11: 30,
        12: 31
    };

    var months = {
        1: 'January',
        2: 'February',
        3: 'March',
        4: 'April',
        5: 'May',
        6: 'June',
        7: 'July',
        8: 'August',
        9: 'September',
        10: 'October',
        11: 'November',
        12: 'December'
    };

    var monthOptions = [];
    var dayOptions = {};
    var yearOptions = [];

    for (var month in monthDays) {
        var days = monthDays[month];
        monthOptions.push('<option value="' + month + '">' + months[month] + '</option>');
        dayOptions[month] = [];
        for (var i=1; i <= days; i++) {
            var day = i;
            dayOptions[month].push('<option value="' + day + '">' + day + '</option>');
        }
    }

    var currentYear = new Date();
    currentYear = currentYear.getFullYear();

    var startYear = currentYear - 120;

    for (var y=currentYear; y > startYear; y--) {
        yearOptions.push('<option value="' + y + '">' + y + '</option>');
    }



    $s(document).ready(function(){
        var monthHtml = '';
        for (var j=0; j < monthOptions.length; j++) {
            var html = monthOptions[j];
            monthHtml += html;
        }

        $s('#ageMonth').html(monthHtml);

        var yearHtml = '';
        for (var i=0; i < yearOptions.length; i++) {
            yearHtml += yearOptions[i];
        }

        $s('#ageYear').html(yearHtml);

        $s('#ageMonth').bind('change', function(){
            var dayHtml = '';
            var month = $s(this).val();

            for (var i=0; i < dayOptions[month].length; i++) {
                dayHtml += dayOptions[month][i];
            }

            $s('#ageDay').html(dayHtml);
        });

        $s('#ageEnterSite').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var date = new Date();
            date.setMonth($s('#ageMonth').val() - 1);
            date.setDate($s('#ageDay').val());
            date.setYear($s('#ageYear').val());

            var maxDate = new Date();
            // alert(maxDate.getFullYear());

            maxDate.setYear(maxDate.getFullYear() - 18);

            if (date <= maxDate) {
                writeCookie('jcsj_age_verified', '1', 30);
                $s('#age-gate').fadeOut(function(){
                    $s(this).remove();
                    $s('body').removeClass('age-gate-visible');
                });
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
            }

        });

        $s('#ageMonth').change(); // load default month
        // $s('#ageDay').prop('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $s('body').addClass('age-gate-visible');
            $s('#age-gate').fadeIn();
        }, 200);
    });
}

if (readCookie('jcsj_age_verified')) {

} else {
    ageGate();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If $_SESSION is not set always will evaluate this

```
  if (is_numeric($expires) && $expires==-1 && !isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated=false;
    }
```

Just fix it and should work.
Assuming that everything else is fine, I would replace

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE["verified"])) {
        $validated=true;
    }
    if (!$validated && isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated=true;
    }
    if (is_numeric($expires) && $expires==-1 && !isset($_SESSION['verified'])) {
        $validated=false;
    }
```

By:

```
if ( (isset($_COOKIE["verified"] && !empty($_COOKIE["verified"])) OR isset($_SESSION['verified']) ) {
    $validated=true;
}
```

So, if user has a non-empty "verified" cookie or a "verified"  session set, it assumes he is validated.

Comment: So how do i set the session? I've tried a bunch of things unsuccessfully.

Comment: Ok i'm doing something wrong that sends me to an all white blank page now. What did I miss?

Comment: You have some parser error. Enable display errors on your php/magento configuration or try to see the source code in browser. By the way, I forgot to close a } at the second block.

Comment: Used a JavaScript redirect instead. Thanks anyway.